# How to embed firefox/Chrome browser in java desktop application to make use of the webrtc API's in firefox?

Tags: java, firefox, javafx, swt, webrtc

Can someone help me in finding a way to embed `firefox/Chrome` browser in `Java desktop application?`

I need to specifically embed `firefox/Chrom`e as I need to use the `webrtc` feature supported by these browsers. I tried `JavaFX`, `SWT with MOZILA`, `WebRenderer`, `JDIC & djproject` but the problem is that `webrtc` is not part of any of the browser, not even `SWT.MOZILA`.

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/Home and here is the java wrapper: https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/java-cef

Comment: Alternatively, you can use the [native API](http://www.webrtc.org/native-code/native-apis) as well.

Comment: @Matthias G, I tried with "cef_binary_3.2171.1979_windows32.7z" but its not having the webrtc api's. When I try to call webrtc api's its throwing error. But as per [link](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/ReleaseNotes) webrtc is supported from CEF version 3.1453.1255 onwards. I don't understand where I went wrong :(.

Comment: @Kevin, thanks for your comment. Here I am trying to avoid using native API's as it needs much effort in compiling the entire webrtc library for windows & writing the JNI for native api's. Is there any other way to get java api's like in "webrtc for android" where we get java api's.

Comment: Little late to the game, but you could try www.frozenmountain.com/icelink (disclaimer: I work there), native Java libs for WebRTC